# Issue with input element hover on Internet Explorer 10+

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Let's have a `label` element with the `for` attribute specified properly. This label will later have some action bound  on click event, so we want to change the label's appearance on hover to indicate the option to click it.

However, if you open IE 10/11 and put your cursor over the label's corresponding input element, the label's `:hover` pseudoclass will activate!

I tried floatng the label and input and setting position: absolute.
The only solution I could find was to change/remove label's `for` or input's `id` so they wouldn't be connected to each other. But this is not a good solution, since it disconnects these two elements semantically and will probably lead to issues with screen readers. Is there any other way to resolve this bug?

JSFiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vq8kN/2/)

JSFidde with broken for-id link: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vq8kN/4/)

Comment: no problem with IE on your first link (i use IE 11)

Comment: I'm on IE11 and I see the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use "for" at all if you change your HTML structure a little bit. And yes, label and input are still "connected".

```
<div>
  <label>
    <span>label</span>
    <input id="test" type="text">
  </label>
</div>
```

Here is example:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/Vq8kN/8/
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want you can get your goal with 2 lines of jquery  (I don't know if you can use it)

working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Vq8kN/12/)**

```
$("input").hover(function(){
    $("label").removeClass('hovertest');
}).mouseout(function(){
  $("label").addClass('hovertest');
});
```

css

```
div {
    margin: 1em auto;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 0.2em;
    border: 1px dotted black;
}
label {
    padding: 0.2em 1em;
}
input {
    width: 200px;
}
.hovertest:hover {
    background: #ccc;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

html

```
<div>
    <label class="hovertest" for="test">label</label>
    <input id="test" type="text"/>
</div>
```